# Plotting a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am very new to MATLAB and am struggling to plot my data. In the program below I have modelled a relation between water level (m.a.s.l) and volume of water captured in a tank. Now I need to plot it in a way that H (water level) be in the Y-axis and V (Volume of the water) be in x-axis. However I have read a lot and tried a lot but still couldn't figure it out. Can Someone Help me PLS ??

I have tried to use simple Plot (X,Y) but it gives error. And so many other suggestions. I also tried fprintf function to have it a s a table in txt then plot it on Excel but always printed the last two H and V. not all of them.

```
    for H = 410.03:0.01:414.57

L = 30; v = 0; fun1 = @(x) (0.3.^2-x.^2).^0.5;

if (H<410.03)

%For the heights below the tank, section 0
dis('No Water in the tank')


elseif (H>=410.03 && H<=410.33)
%section (1) 
 h = .3-(H-410.03) ;   
 a = (0.3.^2-h.^2).^0.5 ;
 A = 2*(integral(fun1,0,a)-h*a);
 V = A*L ;

 disp(['H= ' num2str(H)])
 disp(['V= ' num2str(V)])


 elseif (H>410.33 && H<=410.38)
 % section (1+2)
    h = H-410.33 ;
    V1 = L*(2*(integral(fun1,0,0.3)-0));
    V  = V1+(.6*h+22*h.^2)*L ;

    disp(['H= ' num2str(H)])
    disp(['V= ' num2str(V)])


 elseif (H>410.38 && H<=414.57)
    h = H - 410.38;
    V1 = L*(2*(integral(fun1,0,0.3)-0));


    V2 = V1+(0.085)*L;
    V = V2 + (2.8*h)* L ;
     disp(['H= ' num2str(H)])
     disp(['V= ' num2str(V)])



end
end
```

Comment: I can't understand parts of your code. For example, why in the second `elseif` do you compute little `h` and then do nothing with it? Do you mean to be displaying little `h` instead of big H?

Comment: You override H and V each iteration, so you can't plot or display them, and you see only "last  two H and V". set V to be a vector: define a counter inside the loop, and replace `V=...` with `V(counter)=...`

Comment: I edited the second loop. How do I define a counter in my loop? how do I set a value as a vector? simply by making brackets around them?

Comment: I know my questions are very basic. But it's only one day I started MATLAB for my thesis and I really need help. I really appreciate your help guys

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started, although what I did here might not be the easiest first step to understand.  I made a function H->V out of your code that can take a vector of values H and returns a vector V, suitable for plotting.  If you want, you could make a simpler function that looks more like your original (with if-then-else structure) and takes a scalar H and returns a scalar V.  Then you could loop over the range of H, creating V step-by-step.

First save a function like this (call the file `somefunc.m`):

```
function V = somefunc(H)

% constants
L = 30;
fun1 = @(x) (0.3.^2-x.^2).^0.5;

% set up return value (vector)
V = zeros(size(H));

% Section 1 (pick out the parts of H where it's within the first range)
section1 = find(H>=410.03 & H<=410.33);
h = .3-(H-410.03);
a = (0.3.^2-h.^2).^0.5 ;
% Have to loop here because integral won't take a vector of bounds
for i = section1
    A(i) = 2*(integral(fun1,0,a(i))-h(i)*a(i));
end
V(section1) = A(section1)*L ;

% Section 1+2
section_1plus2 = find(H>410.33 & H<=410.38);
h = H-410.33 ;
V1 = L*(2*(integral(fun1,0,0.3)-0)); % scalar
V(section_1plus2)  = V1+(.6*h(section_1plus2)+22*h(section_1plus2).^2)*L ;

% Section 3
section3 =  find(H>410.38 & H<=414.57);
h = H - 410.38;
V1 = L*(2*(integral(fun1,0,0.3)-0)); % scalar
V2 = V1+(0.085)*L; % scalar
V(section3) = V2 + (2.8*h(section3))* L ;
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
H = 410.03 : 0.01 : 414.57;
V = somefunc(H);

plot(H,V);
xlabel('H')
ylabel('V')
```

I'd avoid having similarly named variables, especially the ones that are distinguished just by upper/lowercase.

Comment: Hey Joshua, Thanks for the very elaborated answer. I am trying to understand what you did here:


1)V = zeros(size(H)) % This makes our V as vector with the initial value of zero  and size(H) makes it to have the same dimension z H, right?


2)The Find function can take scalar and make vector out of them?


When I try to run this, it gives an error that when I see details, it tells me the nested function cannot be inside a control statement. But I don't see any nested function there. What might be the problem?

Comment: 1) yes. 2) no, Find takes a vector and returns a vector of indices into that vector.  so find(isprime(1:20)) returns the indices of the primes in the vector 1:20.  3) If I understand what went wrong: To use a function, you need to save it in a separate file with the same name as the function (e.g. "somefunc.m")  then you can refer to it, either by typing something like the second box at the interpreter, or by saving it as a script (in a separate file!) and running that.